# Import text file into SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, text-files

I have a number of separate text files which i would like to import into an SQL database. The data is not comma separted so that rules out using my idea of importing data by comma. However, the data is across a number of rows. See example text file below. Please could anyone advise how i could import specific data such as the programmed and mean values, shift number, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a machine-generated report. The ideal approach is to have that machine produce a different report--one that has no '/////' or any of that crap, just the data you want to import. So that new report's output might look like this.

```
shift_num, prog_min, mean_sec, att_sec, adt_min
1, 600, 599, 658, 210
...
```

In practice, though, it's often not "possible" to get reports like that. (That is, it's *always* possible for the machine to do it, but often humans are unwilling.) When that happens, use your favorite text-processing language to turn the report into usable data.

I like awk for this kind of stuff. Others like perl.

---

To illustrate, I keyed in this replica of your report. (Saved as test.dat.)

```
ORDER   Nr FG68909                    Q.ty Ordered    99
...
                                         SHIFT Nr. 1

////////
PROGRAMMED                            MEAN

600 min                       JOB TIME        599 sec




AVERAGE Turnaround Time  658 sec
AVERAGE Delivery Time  210 mins
```

Then I wrote this awk program. It makes a lot of assumptions about the layout of your report. Some of them will probably fail on real data.

```
/SHIFT/ {shift = $NF}
/JOB TIME/ {
  programmed = sprintf("%d %s", $1, $2);
  mean = sprintf("%d %s", $(NF-1), $NF);
}
/AVERAGE Turnaround/ {  avg_turnaround = sprintf("%d %s", $(NF-1), $NF);}

# Assumes the line "AVERAGE Delivery" is also the end of the record.
/AVERAGE Delivery/ {  
  avg_delivery = sprintf("%d %s", $(NF-1), $NF);
  printf("%d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'\n", shift, programmed, mean, avg_turnaround, avg_delivery);
  # Clear the vars for the next record.
  shift = "";
  programmed = "";
  mean = "";
  avg_turnaround = "";
  avg_delivery = "";
}
```

The output . . .

```
$ awk -f test.awk test.dat
1, '600 min', '599 sec', '658 sec', '210 mins'
```

Comment: You know you can import data using a comma, is there such a thing as importing data by looking at the number of spaces, or fixed length?

Comment: Yes, *I* can import fixed-width data, and I'm sure the OP can import fixed-width data. But he doesn't have fixed width data. He has a report that's been saved to a file.

Comment: Hello, I'm still struggling with this one and have researched AWK and AWKA but still rather lost. I'm just wondering are there any tutorials or easier ways of extracting specific data from each text file? Thanks

Comment: @user1091114: No tutorials that I know of. I wrote an example program for you. But you're better off attacking this problem at the other end.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a simple application in C# to parse the contents of the file using regex, turn it into one line, and insert semicolons where required.